# LINQtoSQL Not Allowing DateTime Conversion to String

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have found a few threads that have dealt with this issue. Though, they are not in a context that is usefull for me. Pretty much, I am trying to convert a DateTime to string, for rendering it into a MVCContrib Grid. Here is how things look inside of my model:

```
public IQueryable<FindStudentViewModel> GetStudentsProjected()
    {
        var projectedStudents= from p in FindAllStudents()
                                select new FindStudentViewModel
                                {
                                    StudentID = p.StudentID,
                                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                                    LastName = p.LastName,
                                    EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress,
                                    CurrentCollege = p.CurrentCollege,
                                    IAUTerm = p.IAUTerm,
                                    IAUProgram = p.IAUProgram,
                                    InquirySource = p.InquirySource,
                                    InquiryDate = (string)p.InquiryDate.ToString(),
                                    Status = p.Status

                                };

        return projectedStudents;
    }
```

And of course, LINQ does not like this one bit. Pretty much, I need to be able to convert the InquiryDate into a string, and then order the results by InquiryDate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error that your are getting in code?

Comment: Why are you casting `p.InquiryDate` to a string, and then calling the `ToString()?`

Comment: It was the only way it would compile. Here is the error:               title>LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.</title>

Comment: @MarcusNizza You have marked your question as `Linq-to-Sql` but now you are saying you are using `LINQ to Entities`. This is not the same thing.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my appologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering on a *string* representation of a DateTime might not be a very good plan.  Consider the following dates:

```
5/4/2007
9/12/2011
6/4/1904
```

If you order them when they are `DateTime` type, you'll get:

```
6/4/1904
5/4/2007
9/12/2012
```

If you use `.ToString()` on them, then order on it, you'll get:

```
5/4/2007
6/4/1904
9/12/2011
```

Code to test with:

```
var dates = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2012, 9, 12), new DateTime(1904, 6, 4), new DateTime(2007, 5, 4) };
foreach (var item in dates.OrderBy(d => d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.WriteLine();
var temp = dates.Select(d => d.ToString());
foreach (var item in temp.OrderBy(d => d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Instead of casting it to a string, I took Gromer's advice and am keeping it as a DateTime.

Comment: When you keep it as a `DateTime`, you can then have access to all the awesomeness that the .Net `DateTime` has for you, especially if you're going to be displaying this data.